# About newforms of half-integral weight

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms

(Sorry for my poor english..)

I have some questions about newforms of half-integral weight. In Mao's paper ("[A generalized Shimura correspondence for newforms](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jnt.2007.03.005)"), he said: "Ueda defined the set of newforms in the space of weight $k+1/2$ forms of level $4N$..." However, in [Ueda's paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.nmj/1118766959), he only defined newforms in $S_{k+\frac{1}{2}}(\Gamma_0(4N),\chi)$ with $\chi$ a "real" Dirichlet character modulo $4N$. 
In Mao's paper, there is no assumption on $\chi$. So, my questions are as follows:

1. Let $\chi$ be a Dirichlet character modulo $4N$. Then what is the definition of the set of newforms in $S_{k+\frac{1}{2}}(\Gamma_0(4N),\chi)$?
2. Furthermore, assume that $f\in S_{k+\frac{1}{2}}(\Gamma_0(4N),\chi)$ be a half-integral weight modular form. Let $t$ be a square-free integer and 
   \begin{equation}
   Sh_t : S_{k+\frac{1}{2}}(\Gamma_0(4N),\chi) \to S_{2k}(\Gamma_0(4N),\chi^2)
   \end{equation} 
   be a Shimura correspondence. I already know that if $f$ is a Hecke eigenform then $Sh_{t}(f)$ is also a Hecke eigenform. If $f$ is newform then is $Sh_{t}(f)$ also a newform in $S_{2k}(\Gamma_0(4N),\chi)$ ?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Can't you see it is a newform and the level from the Euler product and its functional equation ? ([p.309](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN235181684_0212?tify={%22pages%22:[309],%22panX%22:0.506,%22panY%22:1.291,%22view%22:%22info%22,%22zoom%22:0.867}))